# Subsetting, dat[13:24,2] does not return what I expected in this case

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe

I am trying to work out subsetting in R.

I have a data set with two columns named `Diet` and `Bodyweight`.
Rows `1:12` are the control observations and I want to get the mean of the control group's `Bodyweight` column.

So I use this: `mean(dat[1:12,2])`

Then I want to find out how many of the non-control observations(rows 13:24) are less than the mean of the control observations(rows 1:12).

So I used this:
`dat[dat[13:24,2] < mean(dat[1:12,2]), ]`

Which gave me this:

```
   Diet Bodyweight
3  chow      24.04
10 chow      20.10
12 chow      26.25
15   hf      22.80
22   hf      21.90
24   hf      20.73
```

But I was expecting it to return something like this, where rows 1:12 are not included:

```
   Diet Bodyweight
15   hf      22.80
22   hf      21.90
24   hf      20.73
```

How do I achieve this?

*edit: dput() results:

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(Diet = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("chow", "hf"), class = "factor"), Bodyweight = c(21.51, 
28.14, 24.04, 23.45, 23.68, 19.79, 28.4, 20.98, 22.51, 20.1, 
26.91, 26.25, 25.71, 26.37, 22.8, 25.34, 24.97, 28.14, 29.58, 
30.92, 34.02, 21.9, 31.53, 20.73)), .Names = c("Diet", "Bodyweight"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Comment: **Please post a reproducible example with`dput()`**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it in two steps. First get the targeted rows then apply the logical selection:

```
> dat[ 13:24, ][dat[13:24,2] < mean(dat[1:12,2]), ]
   Diet Bodyweight
15   hf      22.80
22   hf      21.90
24   hf      20.73
```

You can chain together calls to "[" . The second call to "[" is just selecting rows with a 12 item logical vector, but since it is created from the same set of values, it is "syncronized".

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know the row numbers, you could also use the names and values.

```
df[with(df, Diet == "hf" & Bodyweight < mean(Bodyweight[Diet == "chow"])), ]
#    Diet Bodyweight
# 15   hf      22.80
# 22   hf      21.90
# 24   hf      20.73
```

Comment: Thanks, this is probably a better way to do it in the future. It is beyond my ability at this point though.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know the row numbers and do not know the name of the other test variables (in the case you had more test variables than only "hf") but know that the "chow" Diet is your control, you could do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(Diet != "chow", Bodyweight < mean(Bodyweight[Diet == "chow"]))
```

Which returns:

```
#  Diet Bodyweight
#1   hf      22.80
#2   hf      21.90
#3   hf      20.73
```

Answer (score 0):

To seriously improve legibility, partition the dataset - if you do a lot of comparing control to non-control on a lot of columns, this will help. Magic row indices considered bad - it's too easy to make a mistake:

```
# Add a column to split into control/non-control
dat$control <- c(rep(T,12),rep(F,12))

# Get aliases for those partitions... (this makes a copy of the whole df)
dat_n <- dat[dat$control==F,]
dat_c <- dat[dat$control==T,]

# Now the expression is waaay more legible and self-explanatory
dat_n[ dat_n$Bodyweight < mean(dat_c$Bodyweight) ,]
#    Diet Bodyweight control
# 3    hf      22.80   FALSE
# 10   hf      21.90   FALSE
# 12   hf      20.73   FALSE
```